# Use legend in stacked bar Graph along with tooltip d3 js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have done stacked bar graph with the help of this link https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1134768 but i want to customize my existing code of stacked graph in which i have to add d3.legend along with tooltip.

[image: Stacked Graph]

Right now i have completed till tooltip but there is label problem because i have to give value like this 'A:100' from my array data as shown below

```
 var data = [
        {month: "4/1854",total:"100" ,A: "45", B:"45", C:"10"},
        {month: "5/1854",total:"200" ,A:"80", B:"70", C:"50"},
        {month: "6/1854",total:"300" ,A:"0", B:"100", C:"200"},
        {month: "7/1854",total:"400" ,A: "200", B:"100", C:"100"},
        {month: "8/1854",total:"500" ,A:"100", B:"200", C:"200"},
        {month: "9/1854",total:"600" ,A:"100", B:"200", C:"300"},
        {month: "10/1854",total:"700" ,A: "400", B:"100", C:"200"},
        {month: "11/1854",total:"800" ,A:"500", B:"200", C:"100"},
        {month: "12/1854",total:"900" ,A:"100", B:"400", C:"500"},
        {month: "13/1854",total:"1000" ,A:"500", B:"0", C:"500"}
    ];
```

And about d3.legend i don't find any suitable example that give me proper picture that how to use it in my existing code but i have to show like this

[image: legend example]

Here is my full working code

```
var xData = ["A", "B", "C"];

  var parseDate = d3.time.format("%m/%Y").parse;

var margin = {top: 20, right: 50, bottom: 30, left: 50},
        width = 500 - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = 350 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
        .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .35);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
        .rangeRound([height, 0]);

var color = d3.scale.category20();
//console.info(color(0));

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(x)
        .orient("bottom")
        .tickFormat(d3.time.format("%b"));

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(y)
      .orient("left");

var svg = d3.select("#pie").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

data.forEach(function(d) {
      d.month = parseDate(d.month);
      xData.forEach(function(c) {
        d[c] = +d[c];
      });

    })

var dataIntermediate = xData.map(function (c) {
    return data.map(function (d) {
        return {x: d.month, y: d[c]};
    });
});

var dataStackLayout = d3.layout.stack()(dataIntermediate);

x.domain(dataStackLayout[0].map(function (d) {
    return d.x;
}));

y.domain([0,
   d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.total; })
    ])
  .nice();

var layer = svg.selectAll(".stack")
        .data(dataStackLayout)
        .enter().append("g")
        .attr("class", "stack")
        .style("fill", function (d, i) {
            console.info(i, color(i));
            return color(i);
        });

layer.selectAll("rect")
        .data(function (d) {
            return d;
        })
        .enter().append("rect")
        .attr("x", function (d) {
            console.info("dx", d.x,x(d.x), x.rangeBand());
            return x(d.x);
        })
        .attr("y", function (d) {
            return y(d.y + d.y0);
        })
        .attr("height", function (d) {
            // console.info(d.y0, d.y, y(d.y0), y(d.y))
            return y(d.y0) - y(d.y + d.y0);
        })
        .attr("width", x.rangeBand() -1)


        .on("mouseover", function(d){

          var delta = d.y1 - d.y0;
          var xPos = parseFloat(d3.select(this).attr("x"));
          var yPos = parseFloat(d3.select(this).attr("y"));
          var height = parseFloat(d3.select(this).attr("height"))

          d3.select(this).attr("stroke","blue").attr("stroke-width",0.8);

          svg.append("text")
          .attr("x",xPos)
          .attr("y",yPos +height/2)
          .attr("class","tooltip")
          .text(d +": "+ delta); 

       })
       .on("mouseout",function(){
          svg.select(".tooltip").remove();
          d3.select(this).attr("stroke","pink").attr("stroke-width",0.2);

        });


svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(xAxis);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "axis axis--y")
      .call(yAxis)
       .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end");
```

Please provide me some useful suggestion about my graph any help should be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's add a legend and a tooltip for [blocks](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1134768) what you mentioned (I cannot use your code because of it is incomplete). Look at the demo in the hidden snippet below (I rewrite data loading to `d3.tsv.parse` to simplify the example).

First of all, let's increase bottom margin to the legend fits to svg:

```
var margin = {top: 20, right: 50, bottom: 130, left: 20};
```

Adds the legend this way (pay attention to the comments):

```
var legend = svg.append("g") // add g element it will be the container for our legend
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (height + 25) + ")") // move it under the bar cart
    .selectAll(".legend")
    .data(causes.reverse()) // bind data
    .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "legend")
    .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(0," + i * 20 + ")"; }); // put legend items one above the other

legend.append("rect") // append legend items rect
    .attr("x", width - 18)
    .attr("width", 18)
    .attr("height", 18)
    .style("fill", function(d, i) { return z(causes.length - 1 - i);}); // set appropriate color with z scale

legend.append("text") // append legend items text
    .attr("x", width - 24)
    .attr("y", 9)
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .style("text-anchor", "end")
    .text(function(d) { return d; }); // set appropriate text
```

The fastest way to add tooltip use [d3-tip](https://github.com/Caged/d3-tip) library. Add it to your project with `npm` or `script` tag.

Define tooltip this way:

```
var tip = d3.tip()
  .attr('class', 'd3-tip')
  .offset([-10, 0])
  .html(function(data, cause) {
    return "<div class=\"tooltip\">" + cause + ":" + data.y + "</div>";
  })

svg.call(tip);
```

Attach appropriate event handler functions for `mouseover` and `mouseout` event for `rect` elements:

```
layer.selectAll("rect")
  .data(function(d) { return d; })
  .enter().append("rect")
  .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.x); })
  .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.y + d.y0); })
  .attr("height", function(d) { return y(d.y0) - y(d.y + d.y0); })
  .attr("width", x.rangeBand() - 1)
  .on('mouseover', function(d,i,j) { tip.show(d, causes[causes.length - 1 - j]); })
  .on('mouseout', tip.hide);
```

Note: it works for d3v3 if you use d3v4 you will be forced to rewrite `mouseover` handler function a bit.

```js
var causes = ["wounds", "other", "disease"];

var parseDate = d3.time.format("%m/%Y").parse;

var margin = {top: 20, right: 50, bottom: 130, left: 20},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .rangeRoundBands([0, width]);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .rangeRound([height, 0]);

var z = d3.scale.category10();

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom")
    .tickFormat(d3.time.format("%b"));

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("right");

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");


var dataAsString = `date total disease wounds other
4/1854 8571 1 0 5
5/1854 23333 12 0 9
6/1854 28333 11 0 6
7/1854 28772 359 0 23
8/1854 30246 828 1 30
9/1854 30290 788 81 70
10/1854 30643 503 132 128
11/1854 29736 844 287 106
12/1854 32779 1725 114 131
1/1855 32393 2761 83 324
2/1855 30919 2120 42 361
3/1855 30107 1205 32 172
4/1855 32252 477 48 57
5/1855 35473 508 49 37
6/1855 38863 802 209 31
7/1855 42647 382 134 33
8/1855 44614 483 164 25
9/1855 47751 189 276 20
10/1855 46852 128 53 18
11/1855 37853 178 33 32
12/1855 43217 91 18 28
1/1856 44212 42 2 48
2/1856 43485 24 0 19
3/1856 46140 15 0 35`;

var tip = d3.tip()
  .attr('class', 'd3-tip')
  .offset([-10, 0])
  .html(function(data, cause) {
    return "<div class=\"tooltip\">" + cause + ":" + data.y + "</div>";
  })

svg.call(tip);

var crimea = d3.tsv.parse(dataAsString, function(item) {
 return {
   date: parseDate(item.date),
    total: +item.total,
    disease: +item.disease,
    wounds: +item.wounds,
    other: +item.other
  };
});

var layers = d3.layout.stack()(causes.map(function(c) {
  return crimea.map(function(d) {
    return {x: d.date, y: d[c]};
  });
}));

x.domain(layers[0].map(function(d) { return d.x; }));
y.domain([0, d3.max(layers[layers.length - 1], function(d) { return d.y0 + d.y; })]).nice();

var layer = svg.selectAll(".layer")
.data(layers)
.enter().append("g")
.attr("class", "layer")
.style("fill", function(d, i) { return z(i); });

layer.selectAll("rect")
  .data(function(d) { return d; })
  .enter().append("rect")
  .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.x); })
  .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.y + d.y0); })
  .attr("height", function(d) { return y(d.y0) - y(d.y + d.y0); })
  .attr("width", x.rangeBand() - 1)
  .on('mouseover', function(d,i,j) { tip.show(d, causes[causes.length - 1 - j]); })
  .on('mouseout', tip.hide);

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "axis axis--x")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(xAxis);

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "axis axis--y")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + width + ",0)")
  .call(yAxis);

var legend = svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (height + 25) + ")")
  .selectAll(".legend")
    .data(causes.reverse())
    .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "legend")
    .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(0," + i * 20 + ")"; });

legend.append("rect")
    .attr("x", width - 18)
    .attr("width", 18)
    .attr("height", 18)
    .style("fill", function(d, i) { return z(causes.length - 1 - i);});

legend.append("text")
    .attr("x", width - 24)
    .attr("y", 9)
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .style("text-anchor", "end")
    .text(function(d) { return d; });

function type(d) {
  d.date = parseDate(d.date);
  causes.forEach(function(c) { d[c] = +d[c]; });
  return d;
}
```

```css
.axis text {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.legend {
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 60%;
}

.axis line,
.axis path {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.axis--x path {
  display: none;
}

.tooltip {
  background-color: lightblue;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 6px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3-tip/0.7.1/d3-tip.js"></script>
```

Comment: i have used your code for legend and done it successfully but can you give me idea about tooltip in which i have to show label like 'A:100'

Comment: Or you can implement a tip yourself. See examples - http://bl.ocks.org/biovisualize/1016860 https://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/257c360b3650b9f0a52dd8257d7a2d73

Comment: i have used your code but there is error of 'tooltip is undefind' which come on this line of your code ' return "<div class=\"tooltip\">" + cause + ":" + data.y + "</div>";'

Comment: What will happen if you remove `class = \"tooltip\"`?

Comment: when i remove tooltip class the value doesn't appear on UI with error in log , but after i change the line to  this ' return "<strong>"+ cause +":"+"</strong> <span style='color:red'><strong>" + data.y + "</strong></span>"' then it run successfully